# Why MySQL Memory engine is so slow?

Tags: mysql, memory

I'm trying to query INFORMATION_SCHEMA database which mostly driven by MEMORY engine, and I have noticed that queries to such tables are about 20 time slower comparing to MyISAM tables.
In profile section I found that 99% of time consumed caused by "Opening tables" procedure.

Is it normal behaviour for such engines or it's require specific approach?

Comment: Check this once http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19588

Comment: 5 years past since bug report and nothing has been done, very pity.

Comment: Yeah, it is. Can't help further.